# change the css class based on the php/mysql query output values in a table

Tags: php, mysql, css

I am displaying some values from mysql database by using php/html. In my table, i have a field "type of transaction"(txn_type). I have two type of transactions in the type of transaction field (purchase and refund). Is it possible to change the css class bases on value in transaction type? for example

```
if the value is purchase I need to execute this: 

    <td><span class="label label-info label-mini"><?php echo $type ?></span></td>

If it is Refund I need to execute this:

    <td><span class="label label-success label-mini"><?php echo $type ?></span></td>.
```

Please possible if possible.
Attaching my code.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-advance table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
<thead>
<tr>
<th><i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i> Type</th>
<th class="hidden-phone"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Date</th>
<th><i class="fa fa-rupee"></i> Amount</th>
<th><i class=" fa fa-book"></i> Details</th>
<th><i class=" fa fa-calendar-o"></i> Due Date</th>
<th><i class=" fa fa-history"></i> Action</th>

</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
$query = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "select * from dlbcc_purchase order by date(purch_date)desc")or die(((is_object($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"])) ? mysqli_error($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]) : (($___mysqli_res = mysqli_connect_error()) ? $___mysqli_res : false)));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
$id = $row['id'];
$type = $row['txn_type'];
$date = $row['purch_date'];
$amount = $row['purch_amt'];
$dtls = $row['purch_dtls'];
$due = $row['due_date'];
?>

<tr>
<td><span class="label label-success label-mini"><?php echo $type ?></span></td>
<td><?php echo $date ?></td>
<td><?php echo $amount?></td>
<td><?php echo $dtls ?></td>
<td><span class="label label-warning label-mini"><?php echo $due ?></span></td>
<td>

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-trash-o "></i></button>
</td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a condition based on your type, like this:

```
<tr>
<td><span class="label <?php if ($type == 'purchase') { echo 'label-info'; } elseif ($type == 'refund') { echo 'label-success'; }?> label-mini"><?php echo $type ?></span></td>
<td><?php echo $date ?></td>
<td><?php echo $amount?></td>
<td><?php echo $dtls ?></td>
<td><span class="label label-warning label-mini"><?php echo $due ?></span></td>
<td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP to do this. Something like:

```
<?php
if ($type == "purchase") echo $label="label-info";
else if ($type == "refund") echo $label = "label-success";
else // provide some fallback here, if there are more types of transaction
?>
```

Then echo/display the correct class:

```
<td><span class="label <?php echo $label ?> label-mini"><?php echo $type ?></span></td>
```

Comment: thanks for the support. I have tried this, but i am getting this error... could you pls help. Error:  Undefined variable: label in C:\wamp\www\Projects\CCDLB\edidelindex.php on line

Comment: did you include the PHP codes before it is being called? in the <td> line?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe -

```
<?php 

   if ( $type == 'purchase ') {
      echo '<td><span class="label label-info label-mini"> ';
   } else {
      echo '<td><span class="label label-success label-mini"> ';
   }
   echo $type
   echo '</span></td>';
?>
```

Comment: thanks, i have tried this also. its working fine as expected.

Answer (score 0):

if your condition is in a varible called $txn_type 
try this

```
<td class="<?php echo ($txn_type == 'purchase')?("label label-info label-mini":($txn_type == 'Refund')?"label label-success label-mini":"")?>" >
```